# BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count are not supported

Tags: c#, specflow

I'm getting following error when run the feature file using spec flow (Please note i'm trying to automate Notepad using Winappdriver)

Help me to resolve this !

Hooks class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Gherkin.Model;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;
using BoDi;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace Winappdriver_new_3
{
    [Binding]
    class Hooks
    {
        private static ExtentTest featureName;
        private static ExtentTest scenario;
        private static ExtentReports extent;


   //     private readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

        private WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> _driver;

        //public Hooks(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
        //{
        //    _objectContainer = objectContainer;
        //}

        [BeforeTestRun]
        public static void InitializeReport()
        {
            //Initialize Extent report before test starts
            var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"C:\extentreport\SeleniumWithSpecflow\SpecflowParallelTest\ExtentReport.html");
            htmlReporter.Config.Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Standard;
            //Attach report to reporter
            extent = new ExtentReports();


            extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
        }

        [AfterTestRun]
        public static void TearDownReport()
        {
            //Flush report once test completes
            extent.Flush();
        }

        [BeforeFeature]
        public static void BeforeFeature()
        {
            //Create dynamic feature name
            featureName = extent.CreateTest<Feature>(FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title);
        }

        [AfterStep]
        public void InsertReportingSteps()
        {

            var stepType = ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType.ToString();

            //PropertyInfo pInfo = typeof(ScenarioContext).GetProperty("TestStatus", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            //MethodInfo getter = pInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
            //object TestResult = getter.Invoke(ScenarioContext.Current, null);

            if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError == null)
            {
                if (stepType == "Given")
                    scenario.CreateNode<Given>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
                else if (stepType == "When")
                    scenario.CreateNode<When>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
                else if (stepType == "Then")
                    scenario.CreateNode<Then>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
                else if (stepType == "And")
                    scenario.CreateNode<And>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text);
            }
            else if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError != null)
            {
                if (stepType == "Given")
                    scenario.CreateNode<Given>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError);
                else if (stepType == "When")
                    scenario.CreateNode<When>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError);
                else if (stepType == "Then")
                    scenario.CreateNode<Then>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Fail(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.Message);
            }

            //Pending Status
            if (ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioExecutionStatus.ToString() == "StepDefinitionPending")
            {
                if (stepType == "Given")
                    scenario.CreateNode<Given>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                else if (stepType == "When")
                    scenario.CreateNode<When>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                else if (stepType == "Then")
                    scenario.CreateNode<Then>(ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");

            }

        }


        [BeforeScenario]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            var appCapabilities = new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities();
            appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", @"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe");

            _driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appCapabilities);
            // _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

            NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual("Untitled - Notepad", _driver.Title);
            scenario = featureName.CreateNode<Scenario>(ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title);
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            _driver.Quit();
        }



    }
}
```

'

Result Message: BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count are not supported! OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows.WindowsDriver`1[[OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows.WindowsElement, appium-dotnet-driver, Version=3.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] (resolution path: Winappdriver_new_3.Steps.Class1)

Comment: Have you googled for `BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count are not supported!`?

Comment: What version of Spec Flow are you using?

Comment: @mjwills , i have tried using specflow 2.4.1